# string conversion, first character upper of each word

Tags: c#, string

i want to convert:

```
HECHT, WILLIAM
```

to

```
Hecht, William
```

in c#.

any elegant ways of doing this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
string name = "HECHT, WILLIAM";
string s = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name.ToLower());
```

(note it only works lower-to-upper, hence starting lower-case)

Comment: Is that thing in there? Oh my. +1

Comment: @Marc: Does `ToTitleCase()` handle "Peter O'Toole" and "Mary Jones-Smith" properly?

Comment: @Grant: Peter needs a new name, Mary is fine though.

Answer (score 5):

I'd just like to include an answer that points out that although this seems simple in theory, in practice properly capitalizing the names of everyone can be *very* complicated:

- [Peter O'Toole](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000564/)
- [Xavier Sala-i-Martin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xavier_Sala-i-Martin)
- [Salvador Domingo Felipe Jacinto Dalí i Domènech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvador_Dal%C3%AD)
- [Francis Sheehy-Skeffington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Sheehy-Skeffington)
- [Asma al-Assad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asma_al-Assad)
- [Maggie McIntosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggie_McIntosh)
- [Vincent van Gogh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh)

Anyway, just something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string CamelCase(this string s)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            s = "";
        string phrase = "";
        string[] words = s.Split(' ');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word.Length > 1)
                phrase += word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1).ToLower() + " ";
            else
                phrase += word.ToUpper() + " ";

        }
        return phrase.Trim();
    }
```

Comment: @TruthStands: Does not produce the correct results for "Peter O'Toole" and "Mary Smith-Jones".

Comment: True, but it would not be difficult to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I voted Marc's answer up, but this will also work:

```
string s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrConv("HECHT, WILLIAM", VbStrConv.ProperCase,0);
```

You'll need to add the appropriate references, but I'm pretty sure it works on all-upper inputs.

Answer (score -2):

I had problems with the code above, so I modified it a bit and it worked. Greetings from Chile. Good paper.

```
private void label8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
nombre1.Text= NOMPROPIO(nombre1.Text);
}

string NOMPROPIO(string s)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
     s = "";
  string phrase = "";
  string[] words = s.Split(' ');
  foreach (string word in words)
  {
    if (word.Length > 1)
    phrase += word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1).ToLower() + " ";
    else
    phrase += word.ToUpper() + " ";
  }
return phrase.Trim();
}
```

Comment: [Please only use English on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676). For Spanish, there is [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).