# How do I transform a string into a PascalCase string with C#?

Tags: c#, string, camelcasing

I have problem with my code. I don't know what am I doing wrong. I want for user to write some sentence and then program should split written sentence into single words where I use ToUpper on first chars of each word in array and then join the together again without spaces.

my code is:

```
    static void Skrci(string stavek)
    {
        string[] p;
        p = stavek.Split(' ');  // polje separatov

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            if (p[i].Length > 0)
            {
                char zacetnica = Char.ToUpper(p[i][0]);
                p[i] = p[i].Remove(0, 1);
                p[i] = p[i].Insert(0, zacetnica.ToString());
            }
        }
        stavek = string.Join(" ", p);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] p = null;
        Console.Write("Vpiši nek stavek: ");
        string stavek = Console.ReadLine();
        Skrci(stavek);
        Console.WriteLine(stavek);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

I tried Step into to see if I can see what is wrong but I don't know.

Comment: So give an example on how the program goes wrong. We dont really do your homework here.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: Try to use english in your code. It will help people here to understand it better.

Comment: My native language is Slovenian and its hard to write what I need in English.

Comment: @KristyMaitz Your reputation fell because your question was downvoted. One downvote subtracts two points from your reputation, as explained in the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). Downvotes can be a result of people finding your question unclear, poor, or that you perhaps should have researched it more yourself before askig for help. I can recommend to you Jon Skeet's "recipe" for writing the perfect question: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your string to function as a reference, not as a value. Use `ref` keyword for that.

Example:

```
static void Skrci(ref string stavek)
    {
        string[] p;
        p = stavek.Split(' ');  // polje separatov

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            if (p[i].Length > 0)
            {
                char zacetnica = Char.ToUpper(p[i][0]);
                p[i] = p[i].Remove(0, 1);
                p[i] = p[i].Insert(0, zacetnica.ToString());
            }
        }
        stavek = string.Join(" ", p);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] p = null;
        Console.Write("Vpiši nek stavek: ");
        string stavek = Console.ReadLine();
        Skrci(ref stavek);
        Console.WriteLine(stavek);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: `ref` is generally confusing; while it is immensely useful (and I use it lots), for *this* scenario, simply returning the string is far preferable; see Shai's answer for a good example. Also - semantics: the string was **already** being passed "as a reference"; what you mean is pass the string reference *by reference*.

Comment: methods are new to me and am learning proper way to use ref, out ect.

Comment: @KristyMaitz: Thanks for accepting, but Shai's soultion with returning a string from function really sounds better...

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that your function `Skrci` does not return a value (or, update it's parameter (by reference))

Here's a quick fix

```
static string Skrci(string stavek)
{
    string[] p;
    p = stavek.Split(' ');  // polje separatov

    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
    {
        if (p[i].Length > 0)
        {
            char zacetnica = Char.ToUpper(p[i][0]);
            p[i] = p[i].Remove(0, 1);
            p[i] = p[i].Insert(0, zacetnica.ToString());
        }
    }
    return string.Join(" ", p);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] p = null;
    Console.Write("Vpiši nek stavek: ");
    string stavek = Console.ReadLine();
    stavek = Skrci(stavek);
    Console.WriteLine(stavek);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: yes its working now but I have stills spaces between words. Sentence should be with out spaces.

Comment: I had to remove spaces between - return string.Join("", p); - now its working perfectly - thank you Shai

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to convert your string into Camel Case, is to create yourself the following extension method:

```
public static String ToCamelCase(this String source)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(source.ToLower());
}
```

(credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168346/310001)

You can then simply do like this:

```
string stavek = Console.ReadLine().ToCamelCase();
```

*Edit:*
And if you want to remove the spaces between the words, you can of course simply add `.Replace(" ", "")` at the end.

Comment: I never used ToCamel.Case - its one method professor never mentioned.

Comment: @KristyMaitz `ToCamelCase` is a method I've written myself (as shown in the answer), it doesn't exist in the C# language... You can of course write `string stavek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Console.ReadLine().ToLower())` directly, but it's much nicer wrapping it in a function, more clearly explaining its intention.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this is what you are trying to do:

```
    static string Skrci(string stavek)
    {
        string[] p;
        p = stavek.Split(' ');  // polje separatov

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            if (p[i].Length > 0)
            {
                char zacetnica = Char.ToUpper(p[i][0]);
                p[i] = p[i].Remove(0, 1);
                p[i] = p[i].Insert(0, zacetnica.ToString());
            }
        }
        stavek = string.Join(String.Empty, p);

        return stavek;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] p = null;
        Console.Write("Vpiši nek stavek: ");
        string stavek = Console.ReadLine();
        stavek = Skrci(stavek);
        Console.WriteLine(stavek);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

If you want to concatenate the strings without the whitespace then don't user string.Join with " " as separator. Also, you are not printing the result of the method, just your input string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static string Skrci(string stavek)
    {
        string[] p;
        p = stavek.Split(' ');  // polje separatov

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            if (p[i].Length > 0)
            {
                char zacetnica = Char.ToUpper(p[i][0]);
                p[i] = p[i].Remove(0, 1);
                p[i] = p[i].Insert(0, zacetnica.ToString());
            }
        }
        stavek = string.Join("", p);

        return stavek;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] p = null;
        Console.Write("Vpiši nek stavek: ");
        string stavek = Console.ReadLine();
        stavek = Skrci(stavek);
        Console.WriteLine(stavek);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```